# How do you handle an exception for a function that returns an unknown type?

Tags: sml

Say I have the following type and function:

```
exception NotFound
type 'a mytype = (string * 'a) list
fun foo [] = raise NotFound
  | foo (x, b) :: bs = b
```

If I were to call the function and pass in an empty list, it will raise an Exception. Normally the function would return b, which is of type 'a. I want to handle the exception but I don't know what type 'a is, so what do I do here?

Related, but I really just want to return a bool. How do I do so?

Obviously the following code does not work as desired but it illustrates what I am trying to accomplish.

```
fun test mytypeobj = foo mytypeobj handle NotFound => false
    (* return true otherwise *)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains a syntax error because of a left-parenthesis that comes a little too soon:

```
exception NotFound
type 'a mytype = (string * 'a) list
fun foo [] = raise NotFound
  | foo (x, b :: bs) = b
```

> I want to handle the exception but I don't know what type 'a is, so what do I do here?

The exception is unrelated to *'a*, so handling it is a matter of:

```
val bar = foo [] handle NotFound => ...
```

> I really just want to return a bool. How do I do so?
>
> ```
> fun test mytypeobj = foo mytypeobj handle NotFound => false (* otherwise true *)
> ```

Since the function `foo` demonstrates no practical purpose, I am unsure *what* boolean you want to return. If you don't care if the boolean you're returning is the result of computing `foo ...`, you can do the following to discard the result and return a boolean of your choice:

```
fun test bs = (foo bs; true) handle NotFound => false
```

If `b::bs` is a list of booleans and you want to return the first of those, then that's what your function does. You can't be sure, of course, that it's `true`. The pattern I just mentioned is useful for unit testing when a function is throwing the right message. You could for example test that `hd` on the empty list correctly throws `Empty`:

```
fun test_hd_empty = (hd []; false) handle Empty => true
                                        | _     => false
```

This test says that if `hd []` doesn't throw, its result is discarded and the test fails. And if it does throw, but the exception isn't `Empty`, it should also fail.